# Is it possible to add Apache Ant module as dependency under Maven module inside a single project

Tags: java, maven, ant, ivy

I have an ant module and a maven module in a single project , I need to refer the ant module inside the maven module i.e want to add the ant module as dependency under maven module, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Are you running into a problem?

Comment: Could you please share an example if possible, where we can add the ant project as dependency in maven project?